After adding methods in serverpod endpoint, my flutter project doesn't recognize the method
What command should I run after adding methods on Serverpod's endpoint.
I have tried all commands in documentation.
anyone, please help me on this.

"The method 'updateUser' isn't defined for the type 'EndpointExample'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'updateUser'"


Make sure you run serverpod generate (command line tool) from within your project_server folder each time you add/update a model or add/update an endpoint. This command will generate the necessary client-side code for you.

You can also run serverpod generate --watch to automatically keep generating the code when you save changes.
